# Javascript loop through array recursively

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, momentjs

I've run into a bit of an issue trying to map a list of items in javascript. I have  the following array that I'm trying to map:

```
[{"project_id":"EGNL1701","title":"Test Energy Project",
"reservations": 
 [{"start_time":"1519887600000"},{"start_time":"1519891200000"},    
 {"start_time":"1519938000000"},{"start_time":"1519898400000"},        
 {"start_time":"1519902000000"},{"start_time":"1519905600000"}, 
 {"start_time":"1519909200000"},{"start_time":"1529683200000"}, 
 {"start_time":"1529686800000"},{"start_time":"1531893600000"}, 
 {"start_time":"1531897200000"},{"start_time":"1531900800000"}, 
 {"start_time":"1531904400000"}]}, 
{"project_id":"LENL1701","title":"Vive","reservations":[]}]
```

Basically it's a list of reservations per project. All the times are in unix code  in miliseconds. I have no issue trying to convert the times to the right time, however what I do need is to check for reservation blocks of consecutive hours. A reservation is always an hour, so I want to map reservations that are directly after the previous reservation, to be included into the previous reservation so that it forms 1 reservation of multiple hours. So if the list would contain  3 reservations for 10-07-2018 at 10, 11 and 12 o'clock then it should combine those in one object.

The new array should look like this:

```
     [
        {
            title: 'Energy Project',
            startTime: 1530631437,
            endTime: 1530638640
        },
        {
            title: 'HTC VIVE',
            startTime: 1530794845,
            endTime: 1530797390
        }
    ];
```

I'm not sure what the best way is to go about this, I was trying to mess with while and for loops to get it done, but I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop.
Here's the code I have now for checking if the next reservation is an hour after the current reservation in the loop:

```
while (moment.duration(getUnixTime(reservations[index + nextIndex].start_time).diff(getUnixTime(reservation.start_time))).asHours() === 1) {
        nextIndex++;
    }
```

I was hoping one of you might have a good idea on how to do this? I feel like I'm going about this all wrong. It's for a React project, I can use ES6 functions etc.

Comment: What would that one object look like?

Comment: What's the `moment` object?

Comment: @mplungjan `{title: 'test title', startTime: 10-07-2018 12:00, endTime: 10-07-2018 14:00}` roughly like this. I want to be able to know the amount of adjacent hours to calculate the end time of that reservation

Comment: @חייםפרידמן [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: Please update the question with a sample input and matching expected output

Comment: @mplungjan updated with expected output

Answer (score 0):

This might not be complete answer so try this

- Create an empty reservations object R
- Loop through (for each or for ) upto second last item. You can check if next item exists or not.
- Check if the criteria for example next one is one hour after the current one then add them together and add it to R.
- End time of R will become end time of current reservation or the one next to it.
- Move to next one or skip based on what you did in previous step.
- When you reach last item simply add it to R if its not being added in previous step.

One of the assumption is that all reservations are in order. You can order them via sorting functions to avoid loop and check where it fits.

Comment: You dont need d3js you can use native js or whatever library you have. Sorry got carried away as i had d3js included in my project.

Comment: I'm trying to work out your suggestion see if it works. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue using @Farrukh Subhani's suggestion.
First had to sort the list, then loop through it twice. Resulting code:

```
export const mapReservationTimes = reservations => {
const upcomingReservations = [];
reservations.sort((x, y) => {
    return getUnixTime(x.start_time).toDate() - getUnixTime(y.start_time).toDate();
});
for (let index = 0; index < reservations.length; index++) {
    let newReservation = { startTime: '', endTime: '' };
    let reservation = reservations[index];
    newReservation.startTime = getUnixTime(reservation.start_time).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM');
    newReservation.endTime = getUnixTime(reservation.start_time)
        .add(1, 'hours')
        .format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM');
    for (let i = index; i < reservations.length - 1; i++) {
        reservation = reservations[index];
        const nextReservation = reservations[i + 1];
        if (
            moment
                .duration(
                    getUnixTime(nextReservation.start_time).diff(
                        getUnixTime(reservation.start_time)
                    )
                )
                .asHours() === 1
        ) {
            index++;
            newReservation.endTime = getUnixTime(nextReservation.start_time)
                .add(1, 'hours')
                .format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM');
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    upcomingReservations.push(newReservation);
}
return upcomingReservations;
};
```

Thanks a lot for the suggestion, it got me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel this might be a good fit for an `array.reduce`, though this might stem from my personal taste. This solution can and should be simplified and cleaned, but I tried to  convey the general idea so I made it a little more verbose then I think production code should be.

```js
const input = [{"project_id":"EGNL1701","title":"Test Energy Project","reservations": 
  [{"start_time":"1519887600000"},{"start_time":"1519891200000"},    
  {"start_time":"1519938000000"},{"start_time":"1519898400000"},        
  {"start_time":"1519902000000"},{"start_time":"1519905600000"}, 
  {"start_time":"1519909200000"},{"start_time":"1529683200000"}, 
  {"start_time":"1529686800000"},{"start_time":"1531893600000"}, 
  {"start_time":"1531897200000"},{"start_time":"1531900800000"}, 
  {"start_time":"1531904400000"}]}, 
  {"project_id":"LENL1701","title":"Vive","reservations":[]}]

const hourInMilliseconds = 3600000

console.log(input.reduce((acc, project) => {
    const title = project.title
    const sortedReservations = project.reservations.map(r => r.start_time).sort()
    const reservationCount = sortedReservations.length
    const earliest = reservationCount > 0 ? sortedReservations[0] : "none"
    const latest = reservationCount > 0 ? sortedReservations[reservationCount - 1] : "none"
    const projectObject = {
      title,
      startTime: earliest,
      endTime: isNaN(latest) ? latest : (Number(latest) + hourInMilliseconds).toString()
    }

    acc.push(projectObject)
    return acc
  }, [])
)
```

Disclaimer: This assumes that all the reservations in one array item are consecutive, which seems to be the case in your sample data. If this is not the case the function would have to be altered a bit.